# How to know whether self-signing certificate or an internal CA signed certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, esxi

We have Esxi host 5.0 deployed by previous team. When we access the server via the browser, it complains about Certificate(Invalid). We also noted that it is going to expire soon on June 24, 2021. We would like to renew this prior to expiry date above. But before we renew it, we would like to know whether this is self-signing certificate or an an internal CA (it obviously not public CA).

Reference on the Internet said that if "Issuer" and "Subject" have the same value, then it is self-signing certificate. And our show:

```
Common Name: mofdt-blsvr-bs04r14.mof.gov.tl
Subject Alternative Names: mofdt-blsvr-bs04r14.mof.gov.tl
Organization: VMware
Organization Unit: VMware Engineering
Locality: Palo Alto
State: California
Country: US
Valid From: June 24, 2016
Valid To: June 24, 2021
Issuer: CA, localhost.localdom
Serial Number: ca68c0280f2aee6c
```

Would you please help guide us how to know whether the SSL certificate installed on our host is a self-signing or an internal CA?

Thanks very much in advance
Sothun
PS. here is Issuer detail:

```
O = localhost.localdom
C = US
DC = gov.tl
DC = mof
CN = CA
```

Comment: Except SAN your first 6 items (CommonName through Country) are clearly the Subject name (although not labelled), and your Issuer name is different, so the cert is not self-signed. The Issuer name is, as you say, not a public CA so it's an internal CA. Moreover the use of DC=DomainComponent attributes makes it possible, but not at all certain, the internal CA used Microsoft software. You should find a root cert for that CA in the certstores of/for your client matchines. I don't see how any of this helps you, and it isn't a programming question or problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thanks for your time answer my question. our finding is the same as your. the certificate was not a self-signing but an internal CA that signed the esxi host certificate. once again thank you very much